# View ionic Mobile app on Fullscreen

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an ionic mobile app. i runs on a mobile browser. it has static a header. i need to hide the address bar for that web app even when scrolling down, but this does not happen.

it has a header as follows,

```
<meta name="viewport" 
      content="initial-scale=1, 
      maximum-scale=1, 
      user-scalable=no, 
      width=device-width">
```

it runs on a native mobile browser. i built the app using console.
so please help me to hide the address/header bar and run like facebook or other web apps

Answer (score 11):

You can install the statusbar plug-in:

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.statusbar
```

or for [cordova 5.0+](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar):

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

and hide the status bar: `StatusBar.hide();`

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  ionic.Platform.ready(function() {
    // hide the status bar using the StatusBar plugin
    StatusBar.hide();
  });
});
```

Some more info [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/#fullScreen) and a working app [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-weather).

**UPDATE for Ionic 2**

In Ionic 2 things are a bit [different](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/status-bar/).
We still need to install [cordova plugin statusbar](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar#cordova-plugin-statusbar) but we need to import the statusbar from ionic native:

```
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';
```

The main class should roughly look like this:

```
import {App, Platform} from 'ionic/ionic';
import {HomePage} from './home/home';
import './app.scss';

import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';

@App({
  template: `
    <ion-nav [root]="root"></ion-nav>
    <ion-overlay></ion-overlay>
  `,
})
export class MyApp {
  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    this.platform = platform;
    this.initializeApp();
    this.root = HomePage;

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      console.log('Platform ready');
      StatusBar.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

The code is borrowed from the [ionic native repository](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/blob/master/demo/www/app/app.js). A good tutorial can be found [here](http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-2-tutorial-lets-create-our-first-application/).

Comment: 404? Has it been deleted?

Comment: @ZhipengYANG: First link doesn't exist anymore and cannot find it. Sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks. But in fact, I'm finding the plugin for Ionic 2. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Docs for the statusbar in ionic2 can be found [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/status-bar/). Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it helps. Moreover, do you know how can I hide the virtual control buttons? (Back, Home and Multitasking)

Comment: @ZhipengYANG: I would suggest you to open a different question. Let's not pollute the thread with off-topic matters. Cheers.

Comment: OK. Could you answer here?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37550706/how-to-hide-virtual-buttons-and-title-bar-using-ionic-2/37569235#37569235

Comment: @ZhipengYANG: I haven't used Ionic 2 extensively yet. I'll get back to you after some experiments. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and solved it using this code:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
  ionic.Platform.fullScreen();
  if (window.StatusBar) {
    return StatusBar.hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

In Ionic 2 need to install Cordova plugin status bar and we need to import the status bar from ionic native:

```
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';


import {App, Platform} from 'ionic/ionic';
import {HomePage} from './home/home';
import './app.scss';

import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
 templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class MyApp {
 constructor(platform: Platform) {
  this.platform = platform;
  this.initializeApp();
  this.root = HomePage;

   }

 initializeApp() {
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
   StatusBar.hide();
   });
  }
  }
```