# How to hide virtual buttons and title bar using Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

[image]

I'm developing an Ionic 2 Android application.
I want to know how can I hide the control button on the bottom ("← O 口") as well as the title bar on the top?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making an Android app fullscreen with Cordova](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302251/making-an-android-app-fullscreen-with-cordova)

Comment: @theblindprophet Oh, seems it's not for Ionic 2.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22661494/view-ionic-mobile-app-on-fullscreen/23757027?noredirect=1#comment62625147_23757027), we can hide the status bar in Ionic 2 using the following code:

```
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';
import {App, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
//He wrotes 'ionic/ionic', but it doesn't work for me.
constructor(private platform: Platform) {
    this.platform.ready().then(()=>{
        StatusBar.hide();
    }
}
```